# How to reference a page in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, radeditor

I am using a RadEditor editor but I have multiple editortoolbar.xml files to reference with it. I have one file, RadEditor.aspx.cs that holds the information. In the page_load, I am trying to dynamically tie in the xml files and reference them to their respective pages. So if main.html pulls up, then editortoolbar_A.xml is used with it. And for sub.html, then editortoolbar_B.xml is used for that editor and so on... I am not proficient in C# so any help would be great. I use jQuery as well.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;    

namespace Main.Web.Views.Home
{
    public partial class RadEditor : ViewPage    
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

RadEditor has toolbars and each RadEditor toolbar is has a certain amount of buttons attached to it. I'm pairing them up to use the right toolbar for the right editor.

ie:

```
 var main = 'main.html';
 var sub = 'sub.html';
 if (main){
    // then use this toolbar for this editor
 }
 if{
    // then use this toolbar
 }
```

I don't think jQuery will work since its tied in using aspx, thats why I'm thinking C#.

Comment: Can you make your question more clear

Comment: I updated it. If you need more clarification let me know.